# make tablesorter table shrink to fit the page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter plugin table that is dynamically populated by ajax and js, and it works fine except for the fact that it is not adjusting any of the cell widths that have an input tag in them.  For clarification, my table has input cells that the user can change as well as drop down lists that are changeable as well.  When the table is populated the very last column is left off.
Is there a way to adjust this so the user can see the entire table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `widthFixed` option is set to `false` because if `true` and you are dynamically populating the table the column widths will be set in pixels.

---

Did you add css for the inputs? Try including the box-sizing setting:

```
.tablesorter input {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a class on the table in css similar to below

```
table { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I just looked at teh css and the width for the table body is already set to 100%

Comment: Are the cells within the table getting set a width? 

td and tr?